# Using the full jQuery code in a webpage.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to optimize a website performance in the web browser, and would like to use the Chrome code profiler. would it be possible to use the full jQuery code instead of the fully built code which is difficult to read and understand?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not. You just have to change the site to load the full code.

Comment: The site I was looking at was using jquery-1.7.2.js and it works. But the as Prisoner pointed changing it to jquery-1.7.2.js will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll normally load something like this if you're using a CDN:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

just remove the `.min` or you can download the full source (unminified/uncompressed) here: http://jquery.com/download/

To be honest though, if you're getting an error that's leading you to jQuery, the error is with your code, not jQuery.

Comment: +1 I tried googling, surprising that for such a easy question there was no obvious answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy for browsers to unpack packed Javascript code.
The only impact jQuery has on webpage performance is that the page will (maybe) load a little bit slower.
Tip: use the jQuery file from Google's CDNs.